# Roots of unity of quadratic extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I am struggling with finding all roots of unity in $\mathbb{Q}(i)$. I know that if $a+bi$ is a root of unity in $\mathbb{Q}(i)$, then $a^2+b^2=1$, and I know how to find all $a, b \in \mathbb{Q}$ that satisfy that equation. However, I do not know how to filter out the roots of unity. I think there should be a somewhat easier way, for example looking at cyclotomic polynomials. Any help would be very nice.

Comment: I am stuck on how to decide which of the $e^{2\pi i k/n}$ have rational real and imaginary parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\xi \in \mathbb{Q}(i)$ be a root of unity. We know that there exists $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\xi$ is $n$-primitive. So, let's use the suggestive notation $\xi_n = \xi$. Now the cyclotomic extension $\mathbb{Q}(\xi_n) / \mathbb{Q}$ is a subextension of $\mathbb{Q}(i) / \mathbb{Q}$. By multiplicativity of the degree you have $$\phi(n) = [\mathbb{Q}(\xi_n) : \mathbb{Q}] \; | \; [\mathbb{Q}(i) : \mathbb{Q}] = 2$$ You have to look for the $n\in \mathbb{N}$ with $\phi(n)|  2$.

Comment: That does not leave many options :). Thank you very much

Comment: @M.Van  You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

Dresden, G., "[A New Approach to Rational Values of Trigonometric Functions](http://home.wlu.edu/~dresdeng/papers/rattan.pdf)", (preprint).

This paper attacks: "for $c,d$ relatively prime integers (with $d > 0$), the primitive $d^\text{th}$ root of unity $\mathrm{e}^{2\pi \mathrm{i}c/d}$ has degree $\leq 2$ over $\Bbb{Q}$ iff $d \in \{1,2,3,4,6\}$."